# Determine the minimum across SIMD lanes of __m256 value

Tags: c, simd, intrinsics, avx, avx2

I understand that operations across SIMD lanes should generally be avoided.
However, sometimes it has to be done.

I am using AVX2 intrinsics, and have 8 floating point values in an __m256.

I want to know the lowest value in this vector, and to complicate matters: also in which slot this was.

My current solution makes a round trip to memory, which I don't like:

```
float closestvals[8];
_mm256_store_ps( closestvals, closest8 );

float closest  = closestvals[0];
int closestidx = 0;
for ( int k=1; k<8; ++k )
{
    if ( closestvals[k] < closest )
    {
        closest = closestvals[ k ];
        closestidx = k;
    }
}
```

What would be a good way to do this without going to/from memory?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28355912/253056) for techniques which work with SSE and 32 bit ints - you should be able to reuse some of the techniques in the answers, although the "split lane" nature of AVX makes it a little trickier than for SSE.

Comment: @PaulR : For packed singles I would prefer "permutes" instead of the `palignr`-s that you use for the 32 bit ints, but the idea remains the same of course. See my answer below.

Comment: @wim: yes, good point - I notice that clang even changes certain `palignr` instructions to permutes/shuffles "on the fly" (which can make debugging/profiling a little confusing!).

Comment: It's AVX not AVX2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <x86intrin.h>
#include <math.h>
/*  gcc -O3 -Wall -m64 -march=haswell hor_min.c   */
int print_vec_ps(__m256 x);

int main() {
    float x[8]={1.2f, 3.6f, 2.1f, 9.4f,   4.0f, 0.1f, 8.9f, 3.3f};

    /* Note that the results are not useful if one of the inputs is a 'not a number'. The input below leads to indx = 32 (!)     */
//    float x[8]={1.2f, 3.6f, 2.1f, NAN,  4.0f, 2.0f , 8.9f, 3.3f};

    __m256 v0    = _mm256_load_ps(x);                /* _mm256_shuffle_ps instead of _mm256_permute_ps is also possible, see Peter Cordes' comments */
    __m256 v1    = _mm256_permute_ps(v0,0b10110001); /* swap floats: 0<->1, 2<->3, 4<->5, 6<->7                         */    
    __m256 v2    = _mm256_min_ps(v0,v1);
    __m256 v3    = _mm256_permute_ps(v2,0b01001110); /* swap floats                                                     */    
    __m256 v4    = _mm256_min_ps(v2,v3);
    __m256 v5    = _mm256_castpd_ps(_mm256_permute4x64_pd(_mm256_castps_pd(v4),0b01001110)); /* swap 128-bit lanes      */
    __m256 v_min = _mm256_min_ps(v4,v5);
    __m256 mask  = _mm256_cmp_ps(v0,v_min,0);
    int    indx  = _tzcnt_u32(_mm256_movemask_ps(mask));


   printf("             7      6      5      4      3      2      1      0\n");
   printf("v0     = ");print_vec_ps(v0    );
   printf("v1     = ");print_vec_ps(v1    );
   printf("v2     = ");print_vec_ps(v2    );
   printf("\nv3     = ");print_vec_ps(v3    );
   printf("v4     = ");print_vec_ps(v4    );
   printf("\nv5     = ");print_vec_ps(v5    );
   printf("v_min  = ");print_vec_ps(v_min );
   printf("mask   = ");print_vec_ps(mask  );
   printf("indx   = ");printf("%d\n",indx);

   return 0;
}


int print_vec_ps(__m256 x){
   float v[8];
   _mm256_storeu_ps(v,x);
   printf("%5.2f  %5.2f  %5.2f  %5.2f  %5.2f  %5.2f  %5.2f  %5.2f\n",
          v[7],v[6],v[5],v[4],v[3],v[2],v[1],v[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
./a.out
             7      6      5      4      3      2      1      0
v0     =  3.30   8.90   0.10   4.00   9.40   2.10   3.60   1.20
v1     =  8.90   3.30   4.00   0.10   2.10   9.40   1.20   3.60
v2     =  3.30   3.30   0.10   0.10   2.10   2.10   1.20   1.20

v3     =  0.10   0.10   3.30   3.30   1.20   1.20   2.10   2.10
v4     =  0.10   0.10   0.10   0.10   1.20   1.20   1.20   1.20

v5     =  1.20   1.20   1.20   1.20   0.10   0.10   0.10   0.10
v_min  =  0.10   0.10   0.10   0.10   0.10   0.10   0.10   0.10
mask   =  0.00   0.00   -nan   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00
indx   = 5
```

In the previous version of this answer, the 128-bit lanes were swapped with `_mm256_permute2f128_ps`.
In this updated answer `_mm256_permute2f128_ps` is replaced by `_mm256_permute4x64_pd`,
which is faster on AMD CPUs and on Intel KNL, see @Peter Cordes' comments.
But note that `_mm256_permute4x64_pd` requires AVX2, while AVX is sufficient for `_mm256_permute2f128_ps`.

Also note that the results of this code are useless if one of the input values is a 'not a number' (NAN).

Comment: Nice solution - I was guessing 10 or more instructions for this kind of solution, but you've done it in fewer than 10.

Comment: @PaulR: Ok, it is 9 instructions. But at least it should be much faster than a for loop  :-) .

Comment: Thanks, great stuff. I benched it, and it's faster. (not sure by how much, as I benched a larger scope.) Slowest part is the tzcnt which the compiler translates into a conditional jump and a bsf.

Comment: @Bram : Did you use the right compiler flags? With only `gcc -O3 -mavx2` the `tzcnt` instruction is not enabled. With `gcc -O3 -march=haswell` the BMI instruction set (and `tzcnt`) are enabled. Intel processors with AVX2 support, such as Intel Haswell, Broadwell or Skylake, also have BMI support, see also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets) .

Comment: @Bram : Anyway, nice to hear that is works! Which cpu, compiler, and compiler options, do you use for the computations?

Comment: @Wim Clang 3.8.0-2ubuntu4, and -march=haswell did the trick for my i5-4570. Using -O2 at the moment.

Comment: For AMD CPUs and KNL, avoid using `vperm2f128` with the same source vector twice.  [`vpermpd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPERMPD.html) can always replace it with equal or better performance on every CPU, and still uses an imm8 control.  (e.g. twice the throughput and 1/4 the uop count on Ryzen.)  `__m256d _mm256_permute4x64_pd(__m256d a, int control) ;`.  Related: `vshufps` can be 1 byte less code-size than `vpermilps`, but is slower on KNL.

Comment: Also, if you do the `vpermilps` instructions first, the load can fold into it.  (Actually `vpermpd` has the same advantage).  Also, doing the lower-latency in-lane shuffles first may have a tiny advantage for out-of-order execution by letting more insns retire sooner.

Comment: @PeterCordes Good idea to use `vpermpd` instead of `vperm2f128`. I just updated the answer.

Comment: BTW, `vpermpd` is AVX2-only.  `vperm2f128` is AVX1.  Probably a good idea to add a note about that.  That sucks for AMD Bulldozer-family (before Excavator), because they only support AVX1.  I only realized this after my previous comment.